# how to get listview into selecteditem template

Tags: asp.net, events, listview, selectedindexchanged

i have a listview with itemtemplate and Selecteditemtemplate . i have a select button with commandname="Select". I am not able to bring my listview into selectedItem Template. my code is as -

```
 <asp:ListView ID="Listview1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="BikeTypeId"    
        OnItemDeleted="delete" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
   OnItemEditing="editing">
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemplaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BikeTypeId") %></td>
    <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %></td>
    <td height="20px"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Description") %></td>
    <td><asp:Image ID="i" runat="server"   ImageUrl='<%# "Handler.ashx?b_id=" +      Eval     ("BikeTypeId") %> ' /></td>
  <td><asp:Button ID="select"  runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" /></td>
    </tr>

  </ItemTemplate>

 <SelectedItemTemplate>
  <tr bgcolor="yellow"></tr>            
  <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BikeTypeId") %></td>
  <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %></td>
  <td height="20px"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Description") %></td>
  <td><asp:Image ID="i" runat="server"   ImageUrl='<%# "Handler1.ashx?b_id=" + Eval("BikeTypeId") %> ' /></td>
  <td><asp:Button ID="Edit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" /></td>
  <td><asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" /></td>
  </tr>   

  </SelectedItemTemplate>


 <EditItemTemplate>
 <tr>
 <td> <asp:Label ID="ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BikeTypeId") %>'><asp:Label></td>
 <td><asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'>' ></asp:TextBox></td>
 <td><asp:TextBox ID="Des" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Descrription") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox> </td>
  <td><asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="File" /></td>
 <td><asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" /></td>
  <td><asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" /></td>
      </tr> 

    </EditItemTemplate>
```

the code behind is -

```
 protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,   ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
     {
        Listview1.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
        string id = Listview1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
        Response.Write(id);
        bind();}
```

there is no change when i am clicking the select button. Help please.....

Comment: What do you mean? the event `ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged` does not fire?

Comment: yes. even in the debug mode control does not go to the selectedeventchanged .